# Best Practice: Managing system programs from PHP site

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm working on a VPN signup site, which is written in PHP and runs on the same Ubuntu server that the VPN server runs on. It allows users to sign up for VPN services, but currently it just emails the support staff their information, and they manually edit the config files on the server. I'm using PPP to handle authentication, so I have a file containing information like below:

```
# user      server      password            ip
test        l2tpd       testpassword        *
```

In order for a new user to be added to the VPN service, their details must be appended to the above table, and the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xl2tpd restart
```

run in order to apply the new changes. What I am looking to do is automate the process. From what I can tell, there are two options. One is to create a shell script, and then use `shell_exec('./adduser test testpassword');`. The other is to do it directly in PHP, by opening the file, modifying it and saving it again.

From a security and speed point of view, which approach is better, or is there another one which I haven't thought of?

Comment: I'd add them all into a "pending" database  table then cron script once an hour to pull out the pending, append to end of existing config file, save, restart daemon. Run the cron as root that way its isolated from the web front end and let your customers know their vpn will be ready in an hour and they'll receive an email confirming completion.

Comment: There really needs to be a wall between signing up and making the VPN user change.  Do you need to do any kind of authentication or background check on new users?  Doesn't `sudo` require a password?

Comment: @RichardChambers Not usually. Once a user has registered and verified their email we take them to a plan selection page, and after there has been a payment confirmation callback from our payment provider we would normally create their account manually, and this is the step we are looking to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` can be configured to execute just a specific command for a specific user, so modifying your `sudoers` file can mean you can use sudo in a more secure way to execute specific commands.

You could combine this with a wrapper script so that php was only executing a localised script with limited rights.

So your wrapper script, let's call it 'restart_auth.sh` may contain:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo /etc/init.d/xl2tpd restart
```

You would then `shell_exec('restart_auth.sh')` from php to run that script.

You would edit your `sudoers` file to allow the user that the script was run as (your php user) to run `/etc/init.d/xl2tpd`. so if your php user is `www_data` edit sudoers (using `visudo` ) to contain:

```
user host = (www_data) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/xl2tpd
```

Provided no tainted data - that is unvalidated information that may contain shell escape characters - is passed through to a shell exec command then it is secure.

As someone else suggested it may be better to write the data to a pending list then read from that, rather than passing it on a `shell_exec()` line. However that can still introduce insecurities, so making sure the values you are writing to the file are untainted is the most important thing.

Also never run that full script as root even as a cron job, but instead use the same approach with sudoers to only permit the running script to execute specific commands as root. For instance you could allow `sudo "cat changes.txt >> auth_file"`

Comment: This looks to be a good [overview on editing the sudoers file on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos).